# Pyspark: Parallelize a UDF

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to loop through two lists, pass the the combos to a function, and get the following output:

```
ru = ['a', 'b', 'c']
ni = ['x', 'y', 'z']

def my_func(ru, ni):
    print("{} + {}".format(ru, ni))

for i in ru:
    for j in ni:
        my_func(i,j)

# Output

a + x
a + y
a + z
b + x
b + y
b + z
c + x
c + y
c + z
```

Since this is Pyspark, I would like to parallelize it, since each iteration of the function can run independently.

Note: My actual function is a long complicated algorithm in pyspark. Just wanted to post an easy example to generalize.

What is the best way to do this?
​

Answer (score 0):

Use `cartesian`:

```
ru = sc.parallelize(['a', 'b', 'c'])
ni = sc.parallelize(['x', 'y', 'z'])
print(ru.cartesian(ni).collect())
```

For your case,

```
ru.cartesian(ni).map(some_func)
```

Or:

```
def my_func(ru, ni):
    print("{} + {}".format(ru, ni))

ru.cartesian(ni).foreach(lambda t: my_func(t[0], t[1]))

a + z
a + y
a + x
b + y
b + x
b + z
c + y
c + x
c + z
```